# Jpa,Locking,jersey rest service and deadlock issue

Tags: java, rest, jpa

I have few jersey rest service.

```
   service1:- deleteQuestionchoice()
    service2:- postQuestionchoie()
   service3:- updateQuestionChoiceSequence()
   service4:- updateMainQuestion()
```

all 4 are different restful method.
Now EXt js UI is having 10 existing questions choice , now add 5 new choice , delete few existing choice(assume 2) and now .

Here UI issues 5 post request(question choice), 2 delete request(question choice) and  for remaining questionchoice , it issues put request to rearrange question choice sequence. also finally it issues put request on question table.

Now UI submit all post put and delete in one go. Now Since EXT JS rest call are asynchronous, so it gets executed in nay order. so we r facing deadlock issue. can anyone point what would be perfect way to resolve this issue.?

Comment: Why do you think you are getting a deadlock?

Comment: what is the underlying database? is it Oracle?

Comment: @Ashish Patil sql server

Comment: @BetaRide for n number of times, i observed all post for question choice gets executed, The delete works. when it goes for put , There seems to be one put successful and next put fails. sometime 3rd put works. I mean to say order of execution is not guaranteed but in my case i want only after every delete, each put should occur.

Comment: What do you mean with "next put fails" ? How do you see that it fails? What HTTP status do you get? If you get a deadlock, will all future HTTP requests "fail"? What Application Server do you use?